# CCSprite spriteWithFile: returning a nil object

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

After creating a CCSprite, I am adding it to a layer with this code:

```
CCSprite *bg1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"menuback1.png"];
bg1.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
bg1.position = ccp(0, 0);
[self addChild:bg1 z:0];
```

When the program runs, I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'
```

After setting a breakpoint near here and checking the value of `bg1`, I indeed find it to be nil.  `menuback1.png` does exist in the resources folder.  I am using cocos2d 2.0 rc0a.

Comment: The problem is the file is not found. Can you navigate to the build product and ensure that the file does indeed exist?

Comment: Ahh.. It seems that they were not actually added in the resources folder and were therefore not getting included in the product.  Thank you very much! If you post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the file is not found. Can you navigate to the built products directory and confirm that the file exists? If not, try deleting and re-adding the file.